# Serving different static folders per location with nginx

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, static-files

#### TL;DR

I need to serve two containerized apps (each on a different port) hosted on the same machine but located at two very different paths, with their own static sub-folder using an [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) reverse proxy.

#### Context

I went through a lot of Q/A with extra complicated stuff that doesn't help me much to understand the essence on how I can serve some static folders *per location* using [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/).

Let me explain what I mean by 'per location' with a simple and uncluttered starting reverse-proxy configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www;
    server_name my.server.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /app-a {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }

    location /app-b {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
    }
}
```

This is working great, except that the static files (css, js, ...) are not served.

Therefore, I changed it like the following to retrieve these files for `app-b`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www;
    server_name my.server.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /app-a {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }

    location /app-b {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
    }
    location ^~ /static/ {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /home/debian/projects/crystallography/web/app-b/;
    }
}
```

And that's working better; I now have these static files for `app-b`. But still nothing for `app-a` of course.

Now, you see what I'm getting at... I also need to serve `app-a` own static folder.

#### What I've tested

Here are two main ideas that I've tried (and which are not working) + other variations (not working either):

1. **Adding an extra static location** (it seems a priori to be a clean way)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www;
    server_name my.server.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /app-a {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
    location ^~ /static/ {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /media/biology/swamps/frog-migration/app-a/; # this is a totally different path than app-b
    }

    location /app-b {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
    }
    location ^~ /static/ {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /home/debian/projects/crystallography/web/app-b/;
    }
}
```

Which obviously conflicts with the static folder from `app-b`, so `nginx -t` naturally fails:

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/static/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/proxy-pass.conf:24
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

2. **Duplication of the server definition** (this one doesn't sound like a great idea to me):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www;
    server_name my.server.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /app-a {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
    location ^~ /static/ {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /media/biology/swamps/frog-migration/app-a/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www;
    server_name my.server.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /app-b {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
    }
    location ^~ /static/ {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /home/debian/projects/crystallography/web/app-b/;
    }
}
```

Syntax is OK, but I have some warnings with `nginx -t`:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "my.server.org" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "my.server.org" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

But most importantly, `app-b` is no more accessible (404 is returned).

#### Question

With [nginx](https://nginx.org), how could I get two (or more of course) different apps (located at two different paths on a same host machine) to live next to each other, in their own bubble and being served with their **own** static sub-folder (i.e. no interference between the static files of the two apps)?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found this solution, with one server, which is working, but I'm not 100% satisfied as I'd like to avoid the `alias` directive because of the [path traversal vulnerability](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/path-traversal-via-misconfigured-nginx-alias/).

**Disclaimer**: so please don't forget the trailing slash in your alias locations.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    #root /var/www;
    server_name server.domain.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /app-a {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        location /app-a/static/ {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            alias /media/biology/swamps/frog-migration/app-a/static/;
        }
    }

    location /app-b {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
        location /app-b/static/ {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            alias /home/debian/projects/crystallography/web/app-b/static/;
        }
    }

}
```

Especially, it's not working with a `root` directive; as it is sending my pages without any of the static files (error 404 on these static files, which I don't understand why):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    #root /var/www;
    server_name server.domain.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /app-a {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        location /app-a/static/ {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            root /media/biology/swamps/frog-migration/app-a/;
        }
    }

    location /app-b {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
        location /app-b/static/ {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            root /home/debian/projects/crystallography/web/app-b/;
        }
    }

}
```

In addition to the working solution above, I also have had to change the static path in my Flask apps to:
`/app-a/static` instead of just `/static` for app-a and
`/app-b/static` instead of just `/static` for app-b.

But by doing this, you definitely want to put your `app-a` and `app-b` strings somewhere in environment variables instead of hard coding them.